# How can I use CERNLIB in my Fortran code?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, libraries

I am trying to make use of CERNLIB, in particular to start with, of the B100 function (RBINOM). I am using a very simple fortran code that would use the function DBINOM provided by CERNLIB to compute the binomial coefficient.

The problem comes when trying to get access to the function itself. This particular one should be in libmathlib from CERNLIB, but I cannot get access to it. I have tried different commands, but none seem to work

My fortran code looks like:

```
  IMPLICIT NONE      
  INTEGER X,K
  DOUBLE PRECISION ANS
  DOUBLE PRECISION DBINOM

  X = 4
  K = 1
  ANS = DBINOM(X,K)
  WRITE(6,*) 'ANS = ',ANS

  END
```

And then, to compile it, I use:

```
 gfortran -o exemple.exe exemple.f -lmathlib
```

it compiles, but gives a nonsense result, like it does not identify any function in there. For instance, it says that binomial coeff of 3 over 1 is of the order of 10^-314.

If I now manually include the library:

```
 gfortran -o exemple.exe exemple.f libmathlib.a -lmathlib
```

it gives the following output:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: libmathlib.a(binom64.o): undefined reference to symbol 'mtlprt_'
 //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpacklib.so.1_gfortran: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so I'm not sure how to get access to the functions in CERNLIB to use them in my code. Does anyone have an idea or could give an example?

Thank you!

L.

Comment: It seems it was a problem of variable declaration. Now it works, with DOUBLE PRECISION X, INTEGER K, DOUBLE PRECISION DBINOM. However, only with the -lmathlib when compiling, the other problem is still unsolved.

Comment: Is the other problem actually a problem? Why having *both* libmathlib.a and -lmathlib? Isn't some other additional library required for the .a?

Comment: Hi @VladimirF, could be that it's not a problem, I am quite new in what concerns libraries. But sure, probably when using -lmathlib it already includes all the needed libraries. So thank you for the answer!